MongoDB 4.0 to 4.2 Upgrade: Can't Start mongos - Location51091: Regular expression is invalid: invalid UTF-8 string
I recently upgraded MongoDB from version 4.0 to 4.2. My MongoDB setup is a sharded cluster, and after the upgrade, I'm encountering an issue when trying to start the mongos router.
Issue:
When I start mongos, I receive the following error message:
SHARDING [mongosMain] uncaught DBException in mongos main: Location51091: Regular expression is invalid: invalid UTF-8 string

How can I identify and resolve any invalid UTF-8 data in my system that might be triggering this issue?
Thank you for your help!
I follow this one: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.1/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-sharded-cluster/

Potentially unrelated, but there was a critical advisory issued this week at https://www.mongodb.com/resources/products/alerts/potential-data-integrity-issues-sep-2024. If you were using the Node.js driver and Node v22.7.0 to write data it's possible invalid UTF-8 strings may have been written.
